# Repeat posts with jquery click on checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, click

I am trying to do something that I think is really simple. I want to set up a standalone checkbox that, when checked, toggles a field to '1' in a database. When unchecked it toggles that flag back to 0. I have the post side set up just fine, but when clicking I end up with the post happening multiple times.

```
<input name="trackdefect" value="1" type="checkbox" id="trackdefect"><label for="defect">Factory Defect</label>
```

And my javascript:

```
$("input[name=trackdefect]:checked").live('click', function(e) {
   $.post("save.php", { id:"trackdefect",value:"1" });
});

$("input[name=trackdefect]:not(:checked)").live('click', function(e) {
   $.post("save.php", { id:"trackdefect",value:"0" });
});
```

Sometimes it runs once on click, sometimes three times, sometimes four or five times. I'm not sure why. When I use pretty much this same code in fiddle it works fine, no multiples: http://jsfiddle.net/suQfA/4/

(I came up with a way around this of course, a check to see if the toggle is the same as what is there already, so it won't post or log anything, but that's a kludge.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to bind it once

```
$("input[name=trackdefect]").change(function(){
    var val = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
    $.post("save.php", { id:"trackdefect",value: val });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can tell this solved my problem! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `change` event instead of the `click` event on the checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/suQfA/5/

Comment: This did not solve the duplication issue. I am loading the page with this code in it into a tab onto the page which is loaded by Ajax. I am beginning to think that switching away from this tab and then switching back is causing the code to be re-loaded and thus double/triple/etc-binding the change or click event. This might be the problem.

Comment: Yea that would definitely do it. If the event is being bound multiple times, it will execute multiple times. Move the event binding so that it only gets bound once and that should take care of the issue.

Comment: Wirey's answer of not doing two binds and using just one appears to have solved my problem, so maybe it wasn't the tab usage.